# Symfony the same variable for all Twig templates

Tags: model-view-controller, doctrine, twig, symfony

I am writing my own CMS using Symfony 3 right now and i have problem with include the same variables in all controllers.

For example:

I want render logo which i have just upload in my admin panel so i keep URL to it in database and fetch with other data like meta (site descryption, site title etc.) in controller - passing it as array and call in base.html.twig

However base.html.twig extends all other twig templates which i use in controllers so i must fetch it in all of them.

Is there some nice solution for my problem ?

Comment: So are you using: `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` in all your Twig templates? You haven't actually posted any of your code. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thank you.
I have just found solution. I can add some global variables to twig using addGlobal() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer based on your comment.

Use `addGlobal()` method in your base controller like so:

```
$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('variable', $variable);
```

Where `$variable` is the global variable you need.

Comment: I don't understand something. How i can use it in base controller when i have not connected it with others. For example CategoryController isn't similar or connected to HomeController.

Comment: By the way, i found this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html  maybe it's a better solution for you. I could post it as another answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is good solution only for static meta data. I want fetch it via ORM.